# Ocaml List element multiplication

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec intmult =
  fun (aList ,al) ->
    if(List.tl aList == []) then
      ((List.hd aList) *  al)   
    else
      List.hd aList * al :: intmult (List.tl aList , al);;
```

Why it is Wrong ?

Comment: Please take the time and provide some more motivation/explanation, what you observe, and in what respect it does not meet your expectations.

Comment: All those `List.hd`, `List.tl` hurt my eyes. Consider using pattern-matching on lists instead, you'll have cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a better way of writing it:

```
let rec intmult : int list * int -> int list =
   function ([],_) -> [0]   (* this case is not processed by your code *)
   |  ([x] ,al) -> [x * al]    (* this case returns an int in your code *)
   | (x::xs,al) ->  x * al :: intmult (xs, al);;
```

You could also use `List.map`:

```
let intmult (l,m)= List.map (fun x -> x * m) l
```

Answer (score 3):

The two branches of your `if` are returning different types. The first branch returns an `int`. The second (`else`) branch returns a list of ints. An OCaml expression has to have a single type, so you need to make these two types the same somehow.

I'm also a little worried what will happen if you pass an empty list to this function.